# jQuery mobile popup external page

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

Just been looking at the new popup feature in JQM 1.2 and wondering if an external page can be opened in a popup, similar to a dialog?
From the docs it looks like the popup div has to be on the same page as the link that opens the popup.
If that's the case, am I right in thinking it won't degrade very well?
The external page link method using a dialog will degrade fine - you'll just get a link to an external page, but if you open the popup page with a javascript disabled browser, you'll just end up with the popup div displayed somewhere on the main page.
To prevent this are you supposed to use some  styles to hide the popup div?

I'm hoping to change some dialogs to popups but if you can't open an external page in them I'll have to think again :(

Anybody played with popups yet?